# Is there a way to make SSMS's Import Data create the primary keys and identity specs?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2016

I am using SSMS 2016 and the import data functionality doesn't create the primary key and identity specs in the destination tables. Does SSMS 2016 support creating these? I am importing tens of tables so per table setting is not feasible. I am importing into am empty database. (I am aware of restore/backup, creating the tables first and third party compare tools)

Comment: If you have the same policy for auto-generated column key then you could write a procedure which will create it for you in every table. That's just a hint, I'm not familiar with SSMS.

Comment: I don't know what you said but i want this during the import. I can create the tables with all the constraints beforehand and just import the data but I don't want to go through this process.

Comment: Do you wish to create one column that will be a primary key with identity spec for every table (let's call it id) or do you have separate needs for different tables?

Comment: @Kamil I just want the destination tables to have the same primary and identity specs like the source tables. If a column is a primary key, make it a primary key in the dest table. If it is an identity one, same in dest table.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SSMS as I've stated earlier so I'm asking those questions to find if any workaround can be of help for you...